# limit number of chars when getting text from user input in perl on Mac OS

Tags: linux, macos, perl, stdin, macos-sierra

I have the following perl code:

```
  my($result) = "";

  while($line = <STDIN>) {
    $result .= $line;
  }
```

What I want to do basically is to read the user input and store it in a variable ("$result"). The problem is that when the input is too long, the script gets stuck and you will have to ctrl-c to cancel the execution to get out. It sounds like there is a limited number of chars to read . There should be a way to change such a limit.

The perl version I have is: v5.18.2
Mac OS: Sierra 10.12.5

Thanks for any help!

----- additional info --------------------

This is the full code to illustrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


print "Input your suggestion:\n";

my(@lines) = <STDIN>;

print "Your suggestion is:\n";

foreach $l (@lines) {
  print "$l";
}
```

---

Start the script, go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opioid_use_disorder#Cause and copy from "Most people who have an opioid use disorder" to "play a role in dependence and overdose" (too many chars that I cannot copy/paste here), and paste the content to the console as input, and you will see the script halts at "code for seemingl".

Comment: There is no inherent limit to how long a string may be (nothing on this side of crazy anyway).  At certain point some things may stop working but there is absolutely no way that a user can enter those tens of thousands of characters. It's something else that the program does, so can you show us the code that actually causes the problem?  Btw, you should remove the newline after input is read, `chomp $line;` (right after `while`).

Comment: As you said, perl probably does not have such a limit, but Mac OS may.

Comment: Sure, every OS has limits -- but how many characters do you expect?  65K?  For what is normally expected from the user I don't see any limit to be in the way.  You haven't answered my question -- can you show the program, or is this it?  If this is the whole program that bails out after you've typed "too long" of an input (how long is that?), then perhaps something's off with the system or installation.

Comment: OK, thanks, this helps. I did, with your code copy-pasted, and it worked fine for me. My guess then would be that it is about that "copy," in particular that some weird characters get picked up and that they trip it up. What happens if you take a lot of text, but nice normal ASCII?  You can try like this: find a long text file and do `cat lotsa.txt | perl script.pl`. (This way you feed the STDIN.) You may want to redirect output to a file, so you can nicely review what it puts out. I just tried with a file of half a Mb (65K lines).

Comment: The code I offered for test is better written as `perl script.pl < lotsa.txt`.  I used piping since then you can also try hand-picked content, like `echo "chars to confuse program" | script.pl`.

Comment: "cat lotsa.txt | perl script.pl" works. So it is probably as you said -- weird chars. But the purpose of the script is to allow storing of any web copied content into a file. Is there a workaround to achieve such a goal? Thanks!

Comment: OK, that's progress.  It sounds like you want to start the program, copy select text from a web page, and paste to the terminal, so into STDIN. The problem is that the web page may come in any encoding it pleases.  You can try to add `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`, and if the page is in utf8  this may work. However, it may not for another encoding. Also, I am not sure that you can trust that what you copy with the mouse will work when pasted in any case. I don't know that you can get this to work reliably.

Comment: Here is another idea instead.  Start the program with the URL.  It goes and fetches the page, and parses it.  Then, if you wish to be able to select a passage of text, you may prompt for a starting and ending phrases of the selection, which the user picks up with a mouse making sure that it's just ASCII, and that it is long enough to be unambiguous. How does that seem?

Comment: There are many resources on downloading and parsing web pages, and many many SO posts.  Some standard and good modules for the purpose: [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/libwww-perl-6.26/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) (or [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/libwww-perl-6.26/lib/LWP/Simple.pm)), [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~kentnl/HTML-Tree-5.06/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm).

Comment: Btw, your statement "_the purpose of the script is to allow storing of any web copied content into a file_" belongs to the question.  It encapsulates what you actually want very well.  Having that would've saved you days of these back and forth comments, and may have yielded informed answers right away.  (Don't mean to beat on you here, just offering well intended advice.)

Comment: @zdim I understand using wget or similar tools to download web pages to files and parse the files instead. I've done that before. I will try it out and let you know. Thanks much.

Comment: @zdim Just realized that I cannot download a web page to a local file and input from the local file, because very often I need to browse the web page once it's programmatically opened by a browser. I will have to figure out some other means to resolve the problem.

Comment: OK. I don't know exactly what you need.  What I had in mind is the following. You open a page in your browser, look through it, and now you want some part of it saved.  You start your program as `script.pl URL`, the program takes the page (by `wget` if you wish), and parses it into a workable data structure. Then it prompts you for "start-phrase", you copy it and paste into STDIN, then it prompts you for the "end-phrase" and you give it.  Then it goes into its data structures that it had built for the whole page, finds the text between those phrases, and saves it.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, a scalar variable is used to represent a block of information. 
A scalar may refer to an integer, a float, a string, an object, binary information, etc.

> It's a versatile variable with no length limit.

Comment: I tried @lines = <STDIN> as well and had exactly the same outcome: I pasted the information in, and it got truncated on the screen and the program got halted and wouldn't respond to anything except ctrl-c.